# Fortran - copying matrices efficiently

Tags: performance, matrix, copy, fortran

There are a couple places in my code where I copy sparse matrices with about 100,000,000 elements. The issue I am coming into is that I am coping the matrices in a loop that is called around 1000 times and coping the matrix takes about 2 seconds (it takes about an hour to complete with the copying taking the most amount of time). I copy the matrices using an equal sign (i.e. A=B). I use the following to initialize the matrix

```
data a/ myzp * 0.0/
```

which takes almost time to execute, where 'myzp' are the elements in the matrix and 'a' is the matrix.

My question is there a more efficient way to copy a matrix in Fortran than using the equal sign?

Update: 
Here is the code in question that is taking 2 seconds,

```
call cpu_time(t1)
a = b
call cpu_time(t2)
```

where a and b are both matrices.

Comment: Please post more code, the verbal description is not totally clear to me. Especially how the matrix is declared.

Comment: You really didn't add much. How are the matrices defined? Are there any user-defined operators? How does their sparse structure look like?

Comment: Obviously, I meant user=defined assignments, but the definition is more important.

Comment: *is there a more efficient way to copy a matrix*  Probably not.  So much probably not that it is probably not worth your time finding out by writing a variety of alternatives and testing them.  You would be better advised to avoid copying large data structures whenever possible.  If you explained what you are trying to do some bright person might have a bright idea.

Comment: Most likely the compiler has an efficient implementation of the assignment operator.   If your matrix is sufficiently sparse, you could consider a different data structure to store the non-zero elements.  But that would almost certainly require additional, major changes to your code.